# GraalVM Spring Native Error: Main entry point class 'com.springnative.demo.DemoApplication' not found

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am very new to GraalVM and I am trying to build a native image.

I am building a simple example over some official tutorials. And I am still getting an error which cannot find the main class. Here is my pom. What am I missing?
Every setup is in place. I have a simple Rest Controller with a "hello" GetMapping. The application standalone works fine. It's nothing special so I won't post the code cause it's useless. Only in the main class I have the proxyBeanMethods = false on

```
package com.springnative.demo;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ComponentScan("com.springnative")
public class DemoApplication {
    
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DemoApplication.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring-native</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sring-graalvm.version>0.8.4</sring-graalvm.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graalvm-native</artifactId>
            <version>${sring-graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.experimental/tomcat-embed-programmatic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-programmatic</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <BP_BOOT_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_BOOT_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>21.0.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.springnative.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error output:

```
[INFO] Executing: C:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java8-21.0.0.2\jre\lib\svm\bin\native-image.exe -cp C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\experimental\spring-graalvm-native\0.8.4\spring-graalvm-native-0.8.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.5\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.4\spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.28.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.27.0-GA\javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.20\byte-buddy-1.10.20.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.3\jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.3\txw2-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.11\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.4.5\spring-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.4.5\spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.4\spring-orm-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.4\spring-context-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.4\spring-tx-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.4\spring-beans-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.4\spring-aspects-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-security-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.3\spring-boot-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.4.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.13.3\log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.3\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.27\snakeyaml-1.27.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.4\spring-aop-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.4.5\spring-security-config-5.4.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.4.5\spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.4\spring-expression-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.11.4\jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.11.4\jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.11.4\jackson-core-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.11.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.11.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.4.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.43\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jakarta.el\3.0.3\jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.43\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.4\spring-web-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.4\spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\experimental\tomcat-embed-programmatic\9.0.38\tomcat-embed-programmatic-9.0.38.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.200\h2-1.4.200.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.4\spring-core-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.4\spring-jcl-5.3.4.jar;C:\Users\dragos.roban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.4.5\spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar;C:\CeBAS\Tasks\2366\demo\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -H:Class=com.springnative.demo.DemoApplication
Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[com.springnative.demo.demoapplication:9848]    classlist:  11,003.49 ms,  1.80 GB
Error: Main entry point class 'com.springnative.demo.DemoApplication' not found.
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED. You need to actually run before the maven build (`mvn clean package -P graal`).
The `vcvars` command goes something like this:

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars.bat
> mvn clean package -P graal
```

For those interested, here I put a profile
It's very important for `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to be after the native-image-maven plugin to avoid conflicts with Boot repackagi

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>graal</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>21.0.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.springnative.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>native-image</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <image>
                            <builder>${builder}</builder>
                            <env>
                                <BP_BOOT_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_BOOT_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                            </env>
                        </image>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now I am having another issue that I don't know how to treat. I have Microsoft Visual 2019 edition. The path is configured correctly to include the `cl.exe` but somehow this stdio.h file is not present anywhere. Maybe I am using the wrong version.

```
Use -Dspring.native.verbose=true on native-image call to see more detailed information from the feature
[com.springnative.demo.demoapplication:1464]        (cap):     427.65 ms,  2.39 GB
[com.springnative.demo.demoapplication:1464]        setup:   2,338.07 ms,  2.39 GB
Error: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\DRAGOS~1.ROB\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-4416010879664063627\JNIHeaderDirectives.c). Compiler command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '-IC:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java8-21.0.0.2\include\win32' '/FeC:\Users\DRAGOS~1.ROB\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-4416010879664063627\JNIHeaderDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\DRAGOS~1.ROB\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-4416010879664063627\JNIHeaderDirectives.c' ' output included error: [JNIHeaderDirectives.c, C:\Users\DRAGOS~1.ROB\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-4416010879664063627\JNIHeaderDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory]
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: This can be solved by running in the exact window the vcvars64.bat from the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools.

Comment: As mentioned you need to run from the Visual Studio CLI Tools, since that shortcut sets a bunch of necessary environmental variables. I'm having a bit of trouble following the timeline, did that fix your second issue with `stdio.h` or not?

Comment: @Zach yes yes. It solved. But somehow, after a bit of time when I reopened a cmd window, I had to run the script again. Weird.